# Use recursion to find permutations of string using an iterator

Tags: java, recursion, iterator, permutation

As the title implies, I'm having difficulty trying to recursively determine all the permutations of a given `String`. The catch is that `String` has to be given through a constructor of an object and then each of the permutations be found one by one. Basically, it has to work like this:

```java
PermutationIterator iter = new PermutationIterator("eat");
while (iter.hasMorePermutations())
   System.out.println(iter.nextPermutation());
```

Here is the code that I'm using but doesn't seem to work and I don't know how to fix it.

```java
public class PermutationIterator {

    private String word;
    private int pos;
    private PermutationIterator tailIterator;
    private String currentLetter;

    public PermutationIterator(String string) {
        word = string;
        pos = 0;
        currentLetter = string.charAt(pos) + "";
        if (string.length() > 1)
            tailIterator = new PermutationIterator(string.substring(pos + 1));
    }

    public String nextPermutation() {
        if (word.length() == 1) {
            pos++;
            return word;
        } else if (tailIterator.hasMorePermutations()) {
            return currentLetter + tailIterator.nextPermutation();
        } else {
            pos++;
            currentLetter = word.charAt(pos) + "";
            String tailString = word.substring(0, pos) + word.substring(pos + 1);
            tailIterator = new PermutationIterator(tailString);
            return currentLetter + tailIterator.nextPermutation();
        }

    }

    public boolean hasMorePermutations() {
        return pos <= word.length() - 1;
    }
}
```

Right now the program prints "eat" and "eta" but after that it through a `StringIndexOutOfBounds` error off of the second stack. Any help with solving this is much appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to mention that your code throws `StringIndexOutOfBoundException`....right?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than just supplying the fix let me help diagnose your issue and then you can have a go at fixing it.

If you look carefully at your code you'll see that the `hasMorePermutations` condition passes when `pos == word.length() - 1`. That means `nextPermutation` will be run when `pos` is pointing to the last character in the string. But in that case when the third branch executes you increment `pos` and then call `word.substring(pos + 1)`. At that point `pos + 1` will be larger than length of the string which will throw the exception.

I expect the fix will be fairly easy.

Comment: If I were to stop the `.substring()` call when `pos == word.length() - 1` and everything below, what would I return instead? I had it surrounded by an if statement with `hasMorePermutations()` but I couldn't figure out the return because returning the original statement would cause a stack overflow.

Comment: To be honest with you I think your technique of mimicking recursion with stacked iterators is overly complex. Unless you are expecting to use very long strings I would suggest just creating a list of all permutations in your constructor and then iterating through them in your methods. Much simpler and more obvious.

Comment: I'll probably just do that if I can't come up with a solution soon. In any case, this was for a class so I didn't decide to make it this way.

Comment: @Kyefer Here's a hint on the fix: you don't need to append anything past `pos` to `tailString` when you are already at the end of the string - there's nothing there to append! Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I'll give you more direct help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code - generates permutations for any given string

```js
package testing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Permutations {

 /*
  * You will get n! (factorial) - permutations from this
  * 
  * Just like this Example: abc (3! = 6 permutations) [abc acb bac bca cab
  * cbc]
  */
 static String str = "abcd";
 static char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
 static List<String> s1 = new ArrayList<>();
 static List<String> s2 = new ArrayList<>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  // s1 - list stores initial character from the string
  s1.add(String.valueOf(ch[0]));

  // recursive loop - char by char
  for (int k = 1; k < ch.length; k++) {

   // adds char at index 0 for all elements of previous iteration
   appendBefore(s1, ch[k]);
   // adds char at last index for all elements of previous iteration
   appendAfter(s1, ch[k]);
   // adds char middle positins like a^b^C - if prev list stores
   // elements
   // whose size() is 3 - then it would have 2 positions fill
   /*
    * say d is next char - d should be filled in _^_^_ _ positions are
    * previous permuions for 3 chars a,b,c(i.e 6 permutations
    */
   appendMiddle(s1, ch[k], k);
   // for every iteration first clear s1 - to copy s2, which contains
   // previous permutatons
   s1.clear();
   // now copy s2 to s1- then clear s2
   // - this way finally s2 contains all the permutations
   for (int x = 0; x < s2.size(); x++) {
    s1.add(s2.get(x));
   }
   System.out.println(s1);
   System.out.println(s1.size());
   s2.clear();
  }

 }

 private static void appendMiddle(List str, char ch, int positions) {

  for (int pos = 1; pos <= positions - 1; pos++) {
   for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
    s2.add(str.get(i).toString().substring(0, pos) + String.valueOf(ch)
      + str.get(i).toString().substring(pos, str.get(i).toString().length()));

   }
  }

 }

 private static void appendBefore(List str, char ch) {

  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
   s2.add(String.valueOf(ch) + str.get(i));

  }

 }

 private static void appendAfter(List str, char ch) {

  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
   s2.add(str.get(i) + String.valueOf(ch));

  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

do a little change in your hasMorePermutation method as below to solved StringIndexOutOfBounds exception.

```
public boolean hasMorePermutations()
{
    return pos < word.length() - 1;
}
```